# Rails :Add foreign key to primary key of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table exchangeablecurrencies which have primary key consists of two columns, from and to. I want to create table rate_history with foreign key to exchangable currencies.

I have tried creating two foreign key for both primary key mentioned.

```
class CreateExchangeableCurrencies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :exchangeable_currencies, primary_key: %i[from to] do |t|
      t.string :from
      t.string :to

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRateHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rate_histories do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.float :rate
      t.string :from
      t.string :to
      t.timestamps
    end
  add_foreign_key :rate_histories, :exchangeable_currencies,
                column: :from, primary_key: :from, on_delete: 
  :cascade
 add_foreign_key :rate_histories, :exchangeable_currencies,
                column: :to, primary_key: :to, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Here is the error

Column `to` on table `rate_histories` does not match column `to` on `exchangeable_currencies`, which has type `varchar(255)`. To resolve this issue, change the type of the `to` column on `rate_histories` to be :string. (For example `t.string :to`).

Comment: Take a look at [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) gem, it may help.

Comment: The whole design seems precarious, how are you going to handle potential duplicates and the fact that cascades may create orphaned records in the rates history table? The whole compound pk idea is most likely a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using any string, you should use currency code for "from" and "to" columns.

Then, name them as "from_currency_code" and "to_currency_code".

Then mark those "from_currency_code" and "to_currency_code","modified_date_time" as combined unique key as follow.

```
add_index :currency_update, [:from_currency_code, :to_currency_code, :modified_date_time], :unique => true
```